# Seeking GIS data (points) for the Giza pyramids including Z-value for the tops of pyramids

Tags: geospatial, historical

I am not even sure if this data is publicly available or not, but  I am looking for something like this that has been surveyed with a z value (don't care what vertical datum).

It doesn't matter the formats or spatial reference, as long is it is defined.

[image]

Comment: If you're asking for elevation data, earthexplorer.usgs.gov might help, but I sense you're asking for something else?